# Flatmap a collect_set in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframe and I'm using `collect_set()` in agg after using `groupby`. What's the best way to `flatMap` the resulting array after aggregating.

```
schema = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

a = [[1, [23, 32], [11, 22], [9989]]]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(a, schema=schema)

b = [[1, [34], [43, 22], [888, 777]]]

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(b, schema=schema)

df = df1.union(
        df2
    ).groupby(
        'col1'
    ).agg(
        collect_set('col2').alias('col2'),
        collect_set('col3').alias('col3'),
        collect_set('col4').alias('col4')
    )

df.collect()
```

I'm getting this as output:

```
[Row(col1=1, col2=[[34], [23, 32]], col3=[[11, 22], [43, 22]], col4=[[9989], [888, 777]])]
```

But, I want this as output:

```
[Row(col1=1, col2=[23, 32, 34], col3=[11, 22, 43], col4=[9989, 888, 777])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `udf`:

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

flatten = udf(lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x)), ArrayType(IntegerType()))

df.withColumn('col2_flat', flatten('col2'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without UDF I supposed this should work :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_distinct, flatten

df.withColumn('col2_flat', array_distinct(flatten('col2')))
```

It will flatten the nested arrays, and then deduplicates.